# como hacer para que se imprima el vector en pantalla en java

Tags: java

como hacer para qeu se imprima el vector en pantalla en java

Buen dia me podrian ayudar con este codigo lo realize pero nesesito que me imprima los numeros que hay en el vector en pantalla y no se como hacerlo uno independiente  que en uno diga primos,y que  despliegue los numeros primos,pares,impares negativos y positivos de la misma manera estas son las especificaciones que me pidieron

> En el vector Introducir números desde el 1000 hasta 9000 y desde -1000 a 9000 De un vector a otro introducir pares impares primos, positivos y negativos  imprimir vectores resultante mostrar cantidad de pares,impares,primos,negativos y psotivos.

```
package vector_pares_impares_primos;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class classs {


        public static void main(String[]args) {
             Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             int num, n,m=0, par=0, impar=0, nprim=0, n1=0, pos=0, neg=0; 
             int j, d;

            System.out.println("introduce los numeros en el arreglo:");
            n=lector.nextInt();
        
            int M[]=new int[n];
            int M1[]=new int[n]; // par
            int M2[]=new int[n];
            int M3[]=new int[n];  // primo
            
             private static void can() {
                    int i=0;
                    int pos=0;
                    int neg=0;
                    int n=0;
                  do {
                      sytem.out.print("los numeros son negativos ")
                      while(can)
                  }
                 
                  }
            
          
          for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("ingrese un numero entre -1000 y 9000:");
          num=lector.nextInt();
         
          
          // el numero debe estar entre -1000 y 9000 
             while (num<1000 || num>9000) {
             System.out.println(num+" numero incorrecto [-1000,9000] ");
                 System.out.println("ingrese un numero en el rango :");
                 num=lector.nextInt();
             }
           

             M[i]=num;
          }
          for (int i=0; i<M.length;i++) {
              if(M[i]%2==0) {  
                              M1[par] = M[i];
                  par=par+1;
              }else {
                             M2[impar] = M[i];
                  impar=impar+1;
              }
                      // ver si es primo 
                j = 1;
                d = 0;
                while (j<= M[i] && d<=2) {
                     
                    if (M[i]%j==0) {
                        d = d+1;
                    }
                    j = j+1;
                }
                if (d==2) {
                    M3[nprim] = M[i];
                    nprim = nprim+1;
                }   
              
               
          }
        
         

          System.out.println("--");
            System.out.println("Total de numeros pares: "+par);
            for(int x=0;x<par;x++) {
                if(M1[x]!=0)
                    {System.out.print(M1[x]+" ");}
            }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Total de numeros impares: "+impar);
            for(int y=0;y<impar;y++) {
                if(M2[y]!=0) 
                {System.out.print(M2[y]+" ");}
            }
            System.out.println(""); 
            
            System.out.println("Total de numeros primos: "+nprim);
            for(int z=0;z<nprim;z++) {
                if(M3[z]!=0) {
                    System.out.print(M3[z]+" ");}
                }
          System.out.println("");       
          System.out.println("=============================");
        }
          
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es el problema específico con el código? Qué parte del enunciado no se está cumpliendo?

Comment: al momento de que le ingreso un numero negativo el programa me vota error en la consolo intente cuadrar esto para otro arreglo que me cogiera el rango de los numeros negativos entre -1000 y 9000 pero me sigue votando error

Comment: ya intentaste con `Arrays.toString(arreglo)`?

Comment: la profesora aun no nos explica como el Arrays.tostring(arreglo) ya que hasta el momento estamos aprendiendo java @Ruslan Lopez.

Comment: dices ingresar numeros entre `-1000,9000` por lo que debes poner `while (num<-1000 || num>9000)`

Comment: lo intente en el mismo programa que subi aqui y me da un error todo raro incluso lo intente con otro while y no me deja@Dramaturgo

Comment: quiza sea por el metodo **can** que tienes dentro del método main el cual debe ir fuera del método main mas aun esta mal planteado...aqui una [prueba de tu codigo](https://www.codiva.io/p/1ff249a0-7f49-49e1-a16e-38eb1e07ce88)